Is there a repository of WKT definitions for different non-Earth CRS?
QGIS seems to import unknown CRS definitions in WKT format. Given the data from so many non-earth systems out there, is there a repository of WKT format, where one can download them from?

QGIS gives you a good set of Non-Earth CRS's out-of-the-box

The repository that QGIS is using is already on your computer. Find the proj.db file in your PROJ_DATA directory and browse it with any program that understands SQLite. You cannot find the WKT directly from the database because it is not saved as text into any table but it is possible to find Non-Earth systems for example by checking the table "celestial_bodies" and find the name of the body that you want. Let's take "Saturn" as an example. Then you can query the "projected_crs" table
select * from projected_crs where name like 'Saturn%'
IAU_2015    69910   Saturn (2015) - Sphere / Ocentric / Equirectangular, clon = 0       EPSG    4400    IAU_2015    69900   IAU_2015    10      0
IAU_2015    69911   Saturn (2015) / Ographic / Equirectangular, clon = 0        PROJ    PROJECTED_WEST_NORTH    IAU_2015    69901   IAU_2015    10      0
IAU_2015    69912   Saturn (2015) / Ocentric / Equirectangular, clon = 0        EPSG    4400    IAU_2015    69902   IAU_2015    10      0
IAU_2015    69915   Saturn (2015) - Sphere / Ocentric / Equirectangular, clon = 180     EPSG    4400    IAU_2015    69900   IAU_2015    15      0
IAU_2015    69916   Saturn (2015) / Ographic / Equirectangular, clon = 180      PROJ    PROJECTED_WEST_NORTH    IAU_2015    69901   IAU_2015    15      0
IAU_2015    69917   Saturn (2015) / Ocentric / Equirectangular, clon = 180      EPSG    4400    IAU_2015    69902   IAU_2015    15      0
IAU_2015    69920   Saturn (2015) - Sphere / Ocentric / Sinusoidal, clon = 0        EPSG    4400    IAU_2015    69900   IAU_2015    20      0
IAU_2015    69921   Saturn (2015) / Ographic / Sinusoidal, clon = 0     PROJ    PROJECTED_WEST_NORTH    IAU_2015    69901   IAU_2015    20      0
IAU_2015    69922   Saturn (2015) / Ocentric / Sinusoidal, clon = 0     EPSG    4400    IAU_2015    69902   IAU_2015    20      0
IAU_2015    69925   Saturn (2015) - Sphere / Ocentric / Sinusoidal, clon = 180      EPSG    4400    IAU_2015    69900   IAU_2015    25      0
IAU_2015    69926   Saturn (2015) / Ographic / Sinusoidal, clon = 180       PROJ    PROJECTED_WEST_NORTH    IAU_2015    69901   IAU_2015    25      0
...

Select auth_name and code and ask projinfo to tell more
projinfo IAU_2015:69985
PROJ.4 string:
+proj=aea +lat_0=40 +lon_0=0 +lat_1=20 +lat_2=60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=60268000 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs

WKT2:2019 string:
PROJCRS["Saturn (2015) - Sphere / Ocentric / Albers Equal Area",
    BASEGEOGCRS["Saturn (2015) - Sphere / Ocentric",
        DATUM["Saturn (2015) - Sphere",
            ELLIPSOID["Saturn (2015) - Sphere",60268000,0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Reference Meridian",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["IAU",69900,2015]],
    CONVERSION["Albers Equal Area",
        METHOD["Albers Equal Area",
            ID["EPSG",9822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",40,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8821]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",20,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",60,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8824]],
        PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8826]],
        PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8827]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    ID["IAU",69985,2015]]

You can also use the crs-explorer web app:
https://crs-explorer.proj.org/?ignoreWorld=false&allowDeprecated=false&authorities=IAU_2015&activeTypes=PROJECTED_CRS&map=osm
This is just an example, IAU:2015 is not the only authority that has definitions for celestial systems.
